# Plotting multiple subplots with different shapefiles in background

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

I am trying to plot side by side GeoPandas shapefiles using matplotlib but the titles, xlabel and ylabel are not plotting correctly.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,3), sharex=True, sharey=True)

base = subs.boundary.plot(color='black', linewidth=0.1, ax=axes[0])
cluster.plot(ax=base, column='pixel', markersize=20, legend=True, zorder=2)
plt.title('THHZ')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')


base = forest.boundary.plot(color='black', linewidth=0.2, ax=axes[1])
cluster.plot(ax=base, column='forest', markersize=20, legend=True, zorder=2)
plt.title('Forest')
```

This is what I get

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mixture of object-oriented and pyplot-style `matplotlib` interactions. The `plt.`* calls are following a logic of the current axis to act upon. More detail from the `matplotlib` docs here: [Pyplot vs Object Oriented Interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/). I don't know how that behaves with your plotting function calls (code not included in your post).

To be certain of what axes you are interacting with, use the object-oriented calls using the `axes` object you already have:

```
axes[0].set_title('THHZ')
axes[0].set_xlabel('Longitude')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Latitude')
axes[1].set_title('Forest')
```

You can also add `fig.tight_layout()` at the very end for a compacted figure layout.

Comment: TypeError: 'Text' object is not callable

Comment: @pyaj Edited with the correct function calls (`set_` prefix)